# How to integrate Cassandra and Solr for search engine using Spring Framework

Tags: solr, cassandra, search-engine, spring-hateoas

Previously, we used Apache MySQL as data storage layer. And based on that we developed Spring-Hateoas APIs using Spring-Boot 1.2.7 - Spring-Data-JPA.

Now as per new requirement, we wan to develop a search engine.

Firstly, we were asked to move to Cassandra from MySQL as it is NoSQL.
Secondly, we need to build search engine, but we don't want to give up on Cassandra.

So how can we use Cassandra and Solr together and build search engine using Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have been using Spring Data JPA before to access MySql it could be a good decision to go for the spring data projects for Cassandra and Solr:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-solr/

Is that what your are asking for?

Comment: Hello,
We were using MySQL previously. But we have to move to Cassandra. 
Now all our data lies in Cassandra.
I can develop APIs over that. 

But then I have to create Search Engine. I want some information about that.

Comment: So Cassandra is your primary data store and some of the data should got to Solr to be searchable there? If you first have to ask yourself if your data in Solr needs to be updated in realtime or in batch. If you need realtime you need to hook in every data change in Cassandra and transport it to Solr. Otherwise you could try a batch oriented approach: Identify the changes since the last batch run and push all the changes over to Solr. I do not think there is a out-of-the-box solution for synchronizing the data stores.